# I want to add the values of a second list based on conditions of another list

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists:

```
a = [[1, 0.5], [1, 0.5], [2, 1.0], [3, 1.0]]

b = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Now, for each list `a[i]` in `a`, I need to compare the value in the 0'th index of the list `a[i]` and compare it with the 0'th index of the list located in `a[i+1]`. If they are the same, then I need to add the corresponding values in the the list `b` which would be `b[i]` and `b[i+1]`.

For example,
in the lists above, I have `a[0] = [1, 0.5]` and `a[1] = [1, 0.5]`. We see that the first element in both of these lists is `1`. Because they are the same, then in the list `b`, I want to add the elements located in `b[0]` and `b[1]` together, namely, `-0.5` and `-0.5`.

But, `a[2] = [2, 1.0]` and `a[3] = [3, 1.0]`. And, because the 0th position of these two lists do not match, then no action is needed on list `b`, i.e, I do not add elements in `b[2]` and `b[3]` together.

How do I go about approaching this?

Comment: So, for the first example. You want b to become `[0.0,0.0,0.0]` ? In other words, what exactly do you mean by  "adding" the corresponding values of b ? And will b be mutated ?

Comment: No I just want to print the sum of b[0] and b[1]. No mutation on any of these lists. If 0th index value of any of the i'th lists in a match with another 0th index value of (i+1)'th list in a, then print the sum of b[i] and b[i+1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [[1, 0.5], [1, 0.5], [2, 1.0], [3, 1.0]]
b = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0]

# through second to last element
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    if a[i][0] == a[i+1][0]:
        print('for i=={}: {}'.format(i, b[i] + b[i+1]))
    else: # for complete output verification
        print('index "{}" missed'.format(i))
```

Comment: updated my answer because my output formatting was incorrect